# Loading in Datagrid throw Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to display `<Loading />` from react-admin when the list is loading

```
const TabbedDataGrid = (props: TabbedDataGridProps) => {

    const { loading } = useGetList('getListPath');

    return (
        <>
            {loading ? (
                <Loading />
            ) : (
                <Datagrid
                    empty={<ListEmpty />}
                    expand={<ElementShow />}
                >
                    <TextField
                        source="id"
                        label="Id"
                    />
                </Datagrid>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

on page is loading, `<Loading />` is displaying as expected, but after loading from `Hook useGetList` is updated to true, I receive an error:

```
React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by TabbedDataGrid. 
This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks
```

How can I show loading while DataGrid receive new data from dataProvider?

Answer (score 0):

removed `useGetList` hook and get loading from props

```
const { loading } = props;
```

fixed the issue